# Realm+RXJava+Retrofit fetch data from net or local

Tags: android, performance, rx-java, rx-android

I reference the project on github to write my own code
https://github.com/AlbertGrobas/Leaderboards
But still find some question.
In the class 'LeaderboardDataService':

```
public Observable<Leaderboard> getLeaderboard(final String bracket, final boolean forceUpdate) {
    final Observable<RealmLeaderboard> apiObservable = mClient.getApiClient().leaderboardObservable(bracket, Locale.getDefault().toString());
    final Observable<RealmLeaderboard> dbObservable = mDAO.readLeaderboard(mHost, bracket);
return dbObservable.exists(new Func1<RealmLeaderboard, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    @DebugLog
    public Boolean call(RealmLeaderboard leaderboard) {
        return (leaderboard != null);
    }
}).flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<RealmLeaderboard>>() {
    @Override
    @DebugLog
    public Observable<RealmLeaderboard> call(Boolean inDB) {
        return (inDB && !forceUpdate) ? dbObservable : apiObservable;
    }
}).flatMap(new Func1<RealmLeaderboard, Observable<RealmLeaderboard>>() {
    @Override
    @DebugLog
    public Observable<RealmLeaderboard> call(RealmLeaderboard leaderboard) {
        if (leaderboard.getHost() == null) {
            leaderboard.setBracket(bracket);
            leaderboard.setHost(mHost);
        }
        return mDAO.writeLeaderboard(leaderboard, forceUpdate);
    }
}).map(new Func1<RealmLeaderboard, Leaderboard>() {
    @Override
    @DebugLog
    public Leaderboard call(RealmLeaderboard leaderboard) {
        return realmToLeaderboard(leaderboard);
    }
}); }
```

This function is using to determine where to get the data,
local or net. 
Got two question.
1. The first exists function to judge whether data exist in realm.
Only returns a boolean, if realm got the data, need query again,
if there realm is empty, get data from net is no problem.
2. In the next step, if data is from net, update the exist data is fine,
but if the data is from realm, there is no need to update those data.
the operation is useless to the data from realm.

I did some modify to the function:

```
 public Observable<List<ChhPost>> getPosts(final boolean forceUpdate) {
    final String path = "getpostdata";
    final Observable<RealmList<ChhPost>> apiObservable = getApiService().getApiClient().posts(path);
    final Observable<RealmList<ChhPost>> dbObservable = getObservableDAO().readPosts();

    return dbObservable.flatMap(new Func1<RealmList<ChhPost>, Observable<RealmList<ChhPost>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<RealmList<ChhPost>> call(final RealmList<ChhPost> chhPosts) {
            boolean valid = chhPosts!=null && chhPosts.size()>0;
            if(valid && !forceUpdate){
                Observable<RealmList<ChhPost>> postsObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<RealmList<ChhPost>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super RealmList<ChhPost>> subscriber) {
                        subscriber.onNext(chhPosts);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                });
                return postsObservable;
            }else{
                return apiObservable;
            }
        }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<RealmList<ChhPost>, Observable<RealmList<ChhPost>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<RealmList<ChhPost>> call(RealmList<ChhPost> topics) {
            Loge.d("getPosts write to Db");
            return mDAO.writePosts(topics, forceUpdate);
        }
    }).map(new Func1<RealmList<ChhPost>, List<ChhPost>>() {
        @Override
        public List<ChhPost> call(RealmList<ChhPost> topics) {
            List<ChhPost> newTopics = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ChhPost topic : topics) {
                newTopics.add(topic);
            }
            return newTopics;
        }
    });
}
```

The first question seems solved, but the second one still exist.
Did some research, the Rx onNext function only can has one params.
In this case I pass a RealmList of my own class.
The class is s template class for realm and retrofit to fetch data.

The question is how will let the write to realm function knows the 
data is from realm or retrofit, to avoid useless operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RealmList.isValid()` it will return false if the data isn't managed by Realm: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html#isValid--

The current Javadoc as a bit wrong, and we will get that fixed :)

Comment: I use realm to find all objects got RealmResults, and  cast it into postsRealmList, seems the isValid returns false